# How to change an icon on a progress window?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

In Progress 11.3.2 (Developer Studio 3.7 - Eclipse 3.8.2), not using dot net at all:

How do you change the icon a window uses (*.w)?

Found this:
http://www.oehive.org/node/512
Could not get it change any graphics but it had no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the outline view:

[image: Outline view]

You can right click the window (not the frame) and open up the property sheet:

[image]

Click the "Icon Image" icon and select your icon.

Comment: Ah thank you that worked - for most tings but missing the taskbar icon. What is the "Small Icon Image" used for?
How do you change the larger icon that is show in the taskbar?

Comment: The small icon is what you see in the upper left corner of the window (a blue P on the property sheet above). Unsure about the taskbar icon. Might be that you need to change icon of the shortcut starting it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the small-icon as described in this [knowledge entry](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000053193?utm_source=ProgressTalk&utm_medium=forum&utm_campaign=support-kb&utm_term=pmm&utm_content=OpenEdge).

You can also set that property via the property page on the AppBuilder Prospective.

The article mentions Webclient but this will work with a full client as well.